# Two functions variables in to a single function

Tags: c++

I have two variables in two different functions, I'd like to store them in the third function without using global variables.
How to do it?

something like this

```
void function1() { 
  a = 1;
  b = 2;
}

void function2() {
  c = 3;
  d = 4;
}

void function3 () {
  cout << a;  
  cout << b;  
  cout << c;  
  cout << d;  
}
```

Comment: The best solution depends on what your code actually wants to do. With placeholder names like `function1` or `a`, it's hard to give you an appropriate answer that does not only cover the "what's possible" aspect but also the "what's useful" aspect.

Comment: I agree with Christian. You can use a) pass-by-reference, b) return structure or class or tuple or pair c) implement as class member so on... You should choose the one that best suites your context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your functions can `return` values so you can pass variables to other functions, like so

```
std::pair<int, int> function1() {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    return {a, b};
}

std::pair<int, int> function2() {
    int c = 3;
    int d = 4;
    return {c, d};
}

void function3 () {
    int a, b, c, d;
    std::tie(a, b) = function1();
    std::tie(c, d) = function2();
    std::cout << a;  
    std::cout << b;  
    std::cout << c;  
    std::cout << d;  
}
```

[Working demo](http://cpp.sh/8bl5k)

Comment: Or `std::tuple` in place of `std::pair` to be more generic.

Comment: IMHO this is an awkward way to solve a simple problem.  It is not at all obvious what std::tie(a, b) = function1(); does.

Comment: @ravenspoint .... I can't really help if people are aware of or ignorant of the standard library. If they don't know what a function does, they should look it up. Ignorance is not a reason not to use a tool for its primary purpose. [Here's the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) let the knowledge flow!

Comment: Sorry, I disagree.  making code unnecessarily complicated in order to show off your knowledge is not good practice.  Self explanatory code, without reference to any documentation, is most easily maintained.  Remember, debugging is harder than coding - if you write code as complicated as you know how, then you will be unable to debug it.

Comment: Point taken. Though I do not think that this solution is particularly difficult nor complicated, but I will leave that up to the OP. If it is understandable, straight-forwared, and solves their problem then they are free to use this solution. Otherwise they may use any other of the suggested methods.

Answer (score 4):

Make the functions methods of a class, and the variables attributes of the class.

```
class A
{
public:
int a;
int b;
int c;
int d;

void function1() { 
  a = 1;
  b = 2;
}

void function2() {
  c = 3;
  d = 4;
}

void function3 () {
  cout << a;  
  cout << b;  
  cout << c;  
  cout << d;  
}
};
```

Comment: While you *can* do this, I'd highly advise against it. This is pure side effect code.

Comment: This is only one step better than using global variables. Unless something actually fits the OO model, you shouldn't default to throwing functions in a class haphazardously.

Comment: One step better, exactly!  With minimal change to the original code, the original question is answered with straightforward syntax ( i.e no pass by reference or hiding values in pairs )  Why insist on running, when you can walk instead?

Answer (score 4):

Use pass-by-reference:

```
int main() {
    int a;
    int b;
    function1(a, b);

    int c;
    int d;
    function2(c, d);

    function3(a, b, c, d);

    return 0;
}

void function1(int& a, int& b) { 
  a = 1;
  b = 2;
}

void function2(int& c, int& d) {
  c = 3;
  d = 4;
}

void function3(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
  cout << a;  
  cout << b;  
  cout << c;  
  cout << d;  
}
```

Comment: IMHO pass by reference should be avoided.  It is hard to see that  function1(a, b); actually changes the values of a,b as a side effect.

Comment: @ravenspoint The whole *point* of pass by reference is to show that the function will change the values!

Comment: Not so.  In the calling code there is no way to see whether it uses pass by value or pass by reference - the syntax is identical.  You can only tell by finding the function signature.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass them by reference

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void function1(int &a,int &b) {
    a = 1;
    b = 2;

}

void function2(int &c, int &d) {
    c = 3;
    d = 4;
}

void function3(int a1,int b1,int c1,int d1) {

    cout << a1;
    cout << b1;
    cout << c1;
    cout << d1;
}
int main(){
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0;
    function1(a, b);
    function2(c, d);
    function3(a, b, c, d);



}
```